# Notifying a client app to implement Location and Motion key in info.plist when absent

Tags: ios, ios10

Creating a iOS framework which uses Motion and Location framework, As per iOS 10regulations if the motion key has not been added by the client in the info.plist, it will crash.
**I want to notify the client to implement these keys before it crashes**

Comment: Try method swizzling, before the function get called your swizzled method will update the client app

Comment: Can i access the bundle of the clients app , so that i can check if the key is present or absent ?

Comment: Let it crash. The exception will tell them what they have done wrong also make sure your framework documentation explains the need

Comment: I would like to notify the client, Want help in accessing the info.plist of the clients app? Any ways to access the keys ?